# Dynamic Programming - Washing Cars

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to work through the following DP problem is as follows:

A employee at a car wash company has a goal of washing C total cars over the span of next D days. Because of restrictions with his schedule and supplies, he can only wash cars at most D<sub>i</sub> cars a day. Fortunately for him, he has been provided him a list of the maximum number of cars he can wash for each each day for the D days in advance such that [Day 1 = 2 cars, Day 2 = 3 cars, Day 3 = 4 cars). How many many different ways can he meet his goal of washing C cars over the span of D days so that the sum of the total cars over those days equal C. He **must wash at least 1 car** a day. He cannot meet his goal in a # of days < D so it must be done exactly within D days.

For example, if he has a goal of C = 5 cars and it must be done in 3 days D = 3 with the max limits of {2, 3, 4} cars that can be washed each day, the total number of ways he can wash cars would be 5. These 5 ways would be the following combinations:

[1 1 3]
[1 3 1]
[2 2 1]
[2 1 2]
[1 2 2]

I've tried to write the pseudo code and recursion relation using the iterative bottom-up approach but I'm not really sure how to store and track the # of total ways you can wash cars at each sub-problem [i][j]

```
def findWays(T, D, limits):

    M = [[0]*(T+1) for i in range(D+1)]

    for i in range(1, D+1):
        dayLimit = limits[i-1]
        for j in range(1, T+1):
            if i == 1:
                if j <= dayLimit:
                    M[i][j] = 1
            else:
                for k in range(1, j):
                    if (j - k) > dayLimit:
                        continue
                    if (dayLimit - M[i-1][k]) >= 1:
                            M[i][j] = M[i][j] + M[i-1][k]
    print(M)
```

Comment: how do you know that there is DP solution to this problem?

Comment: @EugeneD.Gubenkov I'm gonna go out on a limb and say that it's probably a school problem which specifies to solve it using DP

Comment: hmm, after writing solution myself I think that your pseudo-code actually nails it! :)

Comment: Once an answer comes in, please do not substantially remove detail - it will make more sense to future readers if the answers given follow logically from the question as it stands. I've rolled back to the most substantive version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is dynamic programming solution that works in `O(D*C*C)` time;

Sample matrix for D=3, C till 10 with [2, 3, 4] limits.

[image: sample]

```cs
int NumberOfWays(int c, int d, int[] limits)
{
    // let's t[i, j] be amount of ways j cars can be washed in i days

    var t = new int[d + 1, c + 1];

    for (int day = 1; day <= d; day++)
    {
        int dayLimit = limits[day - 1];

        for (int cars = day; cars <= c; cars++)
        {
            if (day == 1) // first day
            {
                if (cars <= dayLimit)
                    t[day, cars] = 1;
            } else // not first day
            {
                // okay, number of ways given amount of cars can be washed
                // on certain day can be calculated using amounts possible on the previous day

                for (int carsOnPrevDay = 1; carsOnPrevDay < cars; carsOnPrevDay++)
                {
                    if (cars - carsOnPrevDay > dayLimit)
                        continue; // day limit exceeded

                    t[day, cars] += t[day - 1, carsOnPrevDay];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return t[d, c];
}
```

Comment: @Shane, good catch! Seems I forgot to remove `if (dayLimit - t[day - 1, carsOnPrevDay] >= 1)` - that's not needed and does not make any sense. Just fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note: the problem is the same as another common one: how many ways are there of rolling a given total using dice with d1, d2, d3, ..., dn sides.

If there's C[n, i] ways of washing n cars in i days, there's sum(C[n-k], i+1), k = 1..D[i+1]) ways of washing n cars in i+1 days. With the edge conditions: C[0, 0] = 1, C[0, _] = 0.

This directly gives this O(Cmax(D)|D|) algorithm, which uses O(C) space.

```
def cars(C, D):
    r = [1] + [0] * C
    for d in D:
        for i in range(C, -1, -1):
            r[i] = sum(r[j] for j in range(max(0, i-d), i))
    return r[C]

print(cars(5, [2, 3, 4]))
```

You can do a little better, since the inside loop is performing a rolling sum of d values, which can be computed in O(1) time per element of C on average.

```
def cars(C, D):
    r = [1] + [0] * C
    for d in D:
        S = 0
        for i in range(C, -d-1, -1):
            if i >= 0:
                S += r[i]
            if i + d <= C:
                S -= r[i+d]
                r[i+d] = S
    return r[C]

print(cars(5, [2, 3, 4]))
```

Since without loss of generality, max(D) < C, this is O(C|D|) and still uses O(C) space.

If it helps, this code is essentially computing the first C+1 terms of the polynomial P[D[0]] * P[D[1]] * ... * P[D[len(D)-1]], where P[d] = x + x^2 + ... + x^d. The coefficient of x^C in the result is the solution to your problem.

Comment: Nice one! I like your way of making it O(c) in terms of space via rewriting no longer needed values.

Comment: @PaulHankin: I think your solution is similar to this: C[n][i] is number of ways of washing 'n' cars in 'i' days. C[n][i] += C[n-1][i-j] where j >= i. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

On a more educational note, I tried manually running through your algorithm (ignoring the bounding issues) and got this matrix:

[image: Yours]

But you're probably looking more for this (note that I neglected to fill in the invalid values due to laziness):

[image: Mine]

Look into adjusting your summation a bit, particularly on that first day where for some reason it's not possible to wash 2 or 3 cars. Afterwards, you're correct in returning `OPT[D, C]`.

Comment: I think your picture is helpful, but is a little misleading -- on day X we must calculate limit[1] + limit[2] + ... + limit[X] cells. For instance, on day 3 in your example we should go all the way to 9 cars as it will be possible (there will be only 1 way to do it tough)